# Passing user entry to another script

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to use a variable that I get from an entry field in tkinter to another script.

In short:
I want to use the user's input in an entry field in another script. This does not work at all.

Any help highly appreciated!

I tried so far for Script2:

```
from Script1 import App
test = App()
print(test.write_slogan(self))
```

TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'master'

and

```
from Script1 import App
print(App.write_slogan())
```

write_slogan() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

and

```
from Script1 import App
print(App.write_slogan(self))
```

NameError: name 'self' is not defined

and

```
import Script1
print(Script1.App.a)
```

AttributeError: type object 'App' has no attribute 'a'

Script1:

```
from tkinter import *
class App:
  a = 0

  def __init__(self, master):
    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.pack()
    self.slogan = Button(frame,
                         text="Hello",
                         command=self.write_slogan)
    self.slogan.pack(side=LEFT)

    self.entry1 = Entry(root, width=15)
    self.entry1.pack(side=LEFT)

    self.importbutton = Button(frame,
                     text="import",
                     command=self.importing)
    self.importbutton.pack(side=LEFT)

  def write_slogan(self):
    print ("Test!")
    App.a = self.entry1.get()
    print(App.a)
    return App.a

  def importing(self):
    print('Import')
    import Script2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Script2:

```
import Script1
```

Comment: ***"... the mainloop should not be called if I only import a class"***: Read about [executing-modules-as-scripts](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts)

Comment: Thank you, that answers my first question.
Concerning the second one, I still not get it :/

Comment: ***"I want to use the user's input in an entry field in another script."***: Unfortunatly i can't see a reproducible exampel within your given Question for this. [Edit] your Question an extend accordingly.

Comment: In my function "def write_slogan(self)" I am defining the variable "a" as the input of entry1. The function prints that value (just for testing) and returns it.
The user's input (which is saved in variable a) is what I want to use in Script2.
I edit the post, so that the variable "a" gets printed in Script2.
Hope that clarifies it.

Comment: In short: 
I need to use an input from the user in my GUI-script in another script.

Comment: I see, you have difficulties to distinguisch between `class definition` and `class instance`. I assume you want to access `app.entry1` from the already in `Script1` instantiatet `class App`. **Which** script is your `__main__`, `Script1` or `Script2`?

Comment: "I assume you want to access app.entry1 from the already in Script1 instantiatet class App"
Exactly!

Script1 is the main

Comment: I think I see now.
Just found out about the difference between class variable and instance variable.
Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I now defined "a" as a class variable with the initial value 0 (see above)
From Script2 I can access this variable with "print(Script1.App.a)"
But: I am always only getting the value 0, and not what I actually write to entry1 :/

Comment: ***"Script1 is the main"***: Then you have to pass `app` or `self` to your `Script2.class` or `Script2.function`. Are you aware about the difference betwwen `class variable` instead of `class instance variable`. Read [class-and-instance-variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)

Comment: Working!!
I never considered passing self to Script2.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You've since fixed this I believe, but I'm remarking the information for others that may find their way here: The `self` within a class function is the instance python will automatically pass when calling the `def`s. (Unless you're using [classmethod](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/classmethod) or [staticmethod](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/staticmethod) for which are not useful in your use case and are a slightly more advanced topic)

```
# -- Script1 \/

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):
        # self here is automatically passed
        # but you need to pass the "master" arg.
        frame = Frame(master)
        # ... Example:
        self._value = 0

    def set_value(self, val):
        self._value = val

    def get_value(self):
        return self._value

# -- Use (probably in Scipt2)
master = Tk()
app = App(master)
print (app.get_value()) # Notice how we don't pass self
>>> 0

app.set_value("my new value") # This string is the "val" arg
print (app.get_value())
>>> my new value
```

## Scipt1.App.a issue

The main issue you're having with is most likely to do with the way python manages modules. The class is writing to `App.a` in `Script1.App` but not `Script2.Script1.App.a`. This is expected behavior so I recommend instead trying to work with something like:

```
class App:

    def __init__(self, master):
        # ... Make your tk widgets as you already have

    def set_entry_value(self, val):
        self.entry1.set(val)

    def get_entry_value(self):
        self._last_recieved_entry_value = self.entry1.get()

# -- Script2 \/

# The if __name__ == '__main__' is not run on imported
# scripts, only the script python starts execution on
# ~$> python Script2.py
import Script1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = Script1.App(root)

    # Possibly set a default?
    app.set_entry_value("Default value")

    root.mainloop()
    # - Some time after the mainloop is over
    my_lastest_value = root.get_entry_value()
```

This way, you're letting the local instance of objects handle their internal values. If you're looking to set a class member of an alternate module, then doing so in `Script2` may work.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = Script1.App(root)
    # Do something to set the entry
    Script1.App.a = app.get_entry_value()
```

But be warned, that may not scale across multiple modules.